# DB default column value null while saving with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity with the following fields:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "modified_by_user_id")
private User modifiedByUser;

@Convert(converter = LocalDatetimeAttributeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime modifiedDatetime;
```

"modified_by_user_id" and "modified_datetime" columns have a default value in the DB. If I do a manual insert into, the columns will get their default values without being explicitly specified.

However, while saving the entity with Spring Data JPA, the default values is not being calculated and it shows null in the DB

```
    Contributor contributor = new Contributor();
    contributor.setName("a");
    contributorRepository.save(contributor);
```

Why is not the default values being calculated when I save the entity with Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 0):

when you create `contributor` using

`Contributor contributor = new Contributor();`

it will have `null` as value of `modifiedByUser` and `modifiedDatetime` (unless constructor sets those fields) so persisting that object saves those nulls to db

maybe simply marking those fields `not null` in Entity and database will work

but I think better aproach is setting default values in aplication (for example in constructor) , instead database